# VB Script Object Required error - while extracting all zipped folder to another folder

Tags: vbscript, zip

I am trying to iterate all zipped folder inside a folder and extract it into another folder location.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ExtractTo = "C:\Users\070637\Desktop\Mbp\unzipped"

Set SourceFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\070637\Desktop\Mbp")
For each file in SourceFolder.Files
    if Right(LCase(file.Name),4)=".zip" then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(file).items
        objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)        
    End if
Next
```

While executing the script I'm getting an "object required" error in the line

```
set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(file).items
```

Comment: My best bet is that the folder "C:\Users\070637\Desktop\Mbp\unzipped" does not exist. In that case you would get the error message you describe for the line objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip). Error messages in vbs do sometimes not display the correct line number which could be confusing. The other code would work fine imo, but the CopyHere definitely needs the folder to exist

Comment: The folder "unzipped" is present exactly in the same path i mentioned in the code. :(

Answer (score 1):

change to file.path instead of file in set `FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(file).items`

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is? I get the exact same results for file and file.path (I also ran his original code and it worked flawlessly). In which case does path return a different result?

Comment: @Syberdoor - Kindly add to watch and check out both file and file.path. File is object variant that will contain many properties of that file whereas file.path will contain only the string value that is the actual path. So when directly retrieving file.Items, its not sure about for which property you are trying to retrieve its items and hence the error. When specifying file.path, its able to retrieve the item from the specified path

Comment: That's not what I meant, sorry I was not very exact in my question. Of course file is an object and file.path a string but if I print file, or assign file to a string variable I will not get an Error or the DataTypes name in string like in powershell. What I will get as my string is file.path. I would have assumed that Namespace as it takes a string behaves the same. Is there btw some way to find the default behaviour of assigning an object to a string? I couldn't find anything in msdn that hinted to the path being taken here...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add to watch and check out both file and file.path. File is object variant that will contain many properties of that file whereas file.path will contain only the string value that is the actual path. So when directly retrieving file.Items, its not sure about for which property you are trying to retrieve its items and hence the error. When specifying file.path, its able to retrieve the item from the specified path